# Converting Int to Bool

Tags: swift, int, boolean, swift3

In Swift 2.x I believe I could do:

```
let number = 1
let result = Bool(number)

print(result) // prints out: true
```

But since Swift 3 I've been unable to do this and it gives me the error:

> Cannot invoke initialiser for type 'Bool' with an argument list of
>   type '(Int)'

Currently I'm using an extension to convert an `Int` to a `Bool` but I was wondering if there isn't a build in option to do this.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what "converting an int to a bool" even means. Historically, languages like C treat non-zero as `true`, and `0` as `false`, but that's just a consequence of the implementation details of encoding true vs false in memory. When you think about it, it actually makes little sense, semantically. So instead, just use explicitly `i != 0`, to be clear about precisely what you mean. Over-assuming its generalizability and naming it something like `boolValue` is ambiguous. For one, Bash/linux exit codes are the opposite. 0 is good/true, non-zero is bad/false.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

No, there is and has never been an explicit built in option for conversion of `Int` to `Bool`, see [the language reference for `Bool` for details](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/bool).

There exists, still, however, an [initializer by `NSNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/bool/1411965-init). The difference is that implicit bridging between Swift numeric type and `NSNumber` has been removed in Swift 3 (which previously allowed what seemed to be explicit `Bool` by `Int` initialization). You could still access this by `NSNumber` initializer by explicitly performing the conversion from `Int` to `NSNumber`:

```
let number = 1
let result = Bool(number as NSNumber)

print(result) // true
```

As @Hamish writes in his comment below: if we leave the subject of initializers and just focus on the end result (instantiating a `Bool` instance given the value of an `Int` instance) we can simply make use of the `!=` operator for `Int` values (specifically, the operator with signature `func !=(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Bool`), a generalization easily achievable using the `!=` operator approach:

```
let number = -1
let result = number != 0

print(result) // true
```

---

Much like you yourself as well as [@JAL describes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060210/4573247), you could construct your own `Bool` by `Int` initializer, but you might as well consider generalizing this for any type conforming to the [`Integer` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/integer):

```
extension Bool {
    init<T: Integer>(_ num: T) {
        self.init(num != 0)
    }
}

/* example usage */
let num1: Int8 = -1
let num2: Int = 3
let num3: UInt64 = 0
// ....
let result1 = Bool(num1) // true
let result2 = Bool(num2) // true
let result3 = Bool(num3) // false
```

Comment: Or without the obj-c bridge, `let result = number != 0` :)

Comment: @Hamish when I say `let i = 1; let b = Bool(i as NSNumber)`, why am I now told by the compiler to use `init(truncating:)`?

Comment: @matt That's a part of [SE-0170](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md), by using `init(truncating:)` you're acknowledging that the conversion might be lossy as any non-zero number is mapped to `true` (and can't therefore be mapped back to the original number). This is complimented by the introduction of `init(exactly:)`, which will return `nil` if the number cannot be exactly represented, which for `Bool` is any number that isn't 0 or 1.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks, just what I need to know!

Comment: @Hamish Oh dear Swift where have you gone in my life, these kind of comment discussions want to bring me back to it! :)

Comment: Although this is the accepted answer, it is now deprecated and [the above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61528152/323941) should be noted.

Comment: This requires Foundation (for `NSNumber`).

Answer (score 33):

## Swift 4

```
extension Int {
    var boolValue: Bool { return self != 0 }
}
```

## Swift 3

```
extension Integer {
    var boolValue: Bool { return self != 0 }
}
```

#### Usage

```
let number = 2
print(number.boolValue)

let items = ["1"]
print(items.count.boolValue)
```

Comment: How about: `var boolValue: Bool { return self != 0 }`

Comment: Updated for Swift 4: `extension Int {
    var boolValue: Bool { return self != 0 }
}`

Comment: I'd use `Bool?`. In my opinion, `-1.boolValue` as well as `2.boolValue` should return `nil`.

Comment: @RyuX51 ```extension Optional where Wrapped == Int {
    var boolValue: Bool {
        return self?.boolValue ?? false
    }
}
```

Comment: @lingchen I didn't mean an optional Int but I'd prefer `nil` if the Int is not 0 or 1. Like `extension Int {
  var boolValue: Bool? {
    switch self {
    case 0: return true
    case 1: return false
    default: return nil
    }
  }
}`

Answer (score 6):

There is no Boolean initializer that takes an `Int`, only `NSNumber`.  Previously, the `Int` was implicitly bridged to `NSNumber` through Foundation, but that was removed in Swift 3.

You can do something like:

```
let result = Bool(number as NSNumber)
```

Or, you can extend `Bool` and create a custom init that takes an Int:

```
extension Bool {    
    init(_ number: Int) {
        self.init(number as NSNumber)
    }
}
```

Comment: Interestingly enough this doesn't seem to work on Xcode 8.0, but works fine on 8.2/8.3.

Comment: @BonanzaDriver what "doesn't work" about this?  Does it not compile?  Not return the correct bool value?

Comment: This requires Foundation (for `NSNumber`).

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Xcode 9.0.1 and Swift 3.0.

```
let result = (number as NSNumber).boolValue
```

which is working very well for me.

Comment: This requires Foundation (for `NSNumber`).

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5**

```
let number = 1
let result = Bool(truncating: number as NSNumber) //here result will be false if the number's value is 0 and it will be true for any other number's value

print(result)
```

Comment: This requires Foundation (for `NSNumber`).

Answer (score 1):

```
let iFalse: Int = 0
let iTrue: Int = 1
let iNil: Int = 2 //or any number other than 0 & 1

Bool(exactly: iFalse as NSNumber) //false
Bool(exactly: iTrue as NSNumber) //true
Bool(exactly: iNil as NSNumber) //nil
```

Comment: This requires Foundation (for `NSNumber`).

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** try this

```
extension Int32 {
    var boolValue: Bool {
        return (self as NSNumber).boolValue
    }
}
```

or

```
extension Int32 {
    var boolValue: Bool {
        return Bool.init(truncating: NSNumber.init(value: self))
    }
}
```

Comment: This requires Foundation (for `NSNumber`).

Answer (score 0):

something like this. Check if the condition is true and return

```
let result = number == 1 ? true : false
```

Comment: The more common conversion would be `number == 0 ? false : true`. Or simply: `let result = number != 0`.