# Converting Boolean value to Integer value in Swift

Tags: swift, swift3, integer, boolean

I was converting from Swift 2 to Swift 3. I noticed that I cannot convert a boolean value to integer value in Swift 3.

```
let p1 = ("a" == "a") //true

print(true)           //"true\n"
print(p1)             //"true\n"

Int(true)             //1

Int(p1)               //error
```

For example these syntaxes worked fine in Swift 2. But in Swift 3, `print(p1)` yields an error.

The error is `error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Int' with an argument list of type '((Bool))'`

I understand why the errors are happening. Can anyone explain what is the reason for this safety and how to convert from Bool to Int in Swift 3?

Comment: For Swift 4, see my [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44423340/1966109) for a similar question.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## Swift 5

> Bool -> Int

```
extension Bool {
    var intValue: Int {
        return self ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

> Int -> Bool

```
extension Int {
    var boolValue: Bool {
        return self != 0 
    }
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! This is definitely my preferred solution. It adheres to Swift conventions more than other solutions here.

Comment: And to go in the opposite direction 
(Int -> Bool) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45008003/1382210

Comment: Never thought to solve it this way. This is quite good. Works like NSNumber.

Comment: Amazing mate. You have just saved me some time and head-scratching :)

Answer (score 73):

You could use the ternary operator to convert a Bool to Int:

```
let result = condition ? 1 : 0
```

`result` will be 1 if `condition` is true, 0 is `condition` is false.

Comment: Ok, so casting from Boolean to Integer value is a no go in swift 3?

Comment: I don't believe this conversion was really ever part of Swift. I believe it was a side-effect of implicit conversions through NSNumber. Implicit Bool/Int conversions are an old source of bugs in C (in particular, because non-zero numbers like "2" is "true-ish" but not equal to `true`). Swift has actively tried to avoid these historic sources of bugs.

Answer (score 21):

Try this,

```
let p1 = ("a" == "a") //true
print(true)           //"true\n"
print(p1)             //"true\n"

Int(true)             //1

Int(NSNumber(value:p1)) //1
```

Comment: Seems deprecated

Answer (score 13):

EDIT - From conversations in the comments, it is becoming clearer that the second way of doing this below (Int.init overload) is more in the style of where Swift is headed.

Alternatively, if this were something you were doing a lot of in your app, you could create a protocol and extend each type you need to convert to `Int` with it.

```
extension Bool: IntValue {
    func intValue() -> Int {
        if self {
            return 1
        }
        return 0
    }
}

protocol IntValue {
    func intValue() -> Int
}

print("\(true.intValue())") //prints "1"
```

EDIT- To cover an example of the case mentioned by Rob Napier in the comments below, one could do something like this:

```
extension Int {
    init(_ bool:Bool) {
        self = bool ? 1 : 0
    }
}

let myBool = true
print("Integer value of \(myBool) is \(Int(myBool)).")
```

Comment: Or combine @eric-aya 's ternary op recommendation with a protocol for maximum conciseness!

Comment: This approach has generally been discouraged by the core Swift team. They recommend `Int.init` overloads rather than methods to perform full-width conversions.

Comment: Any documentation I could read to that effect @Rob-napier? I'd like to know more about why it's discouraged and the discussion leading to that decision.

Comment: I can't put my hands on a conversation right now; buried somewhere in swift-evo. But you can see the results of the opinion by watching how stdlib has evolved. For example, see https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0006-apply-api-guidelines-to-the-standard-library.md and note where `...value` methods have been converted to `init` (there were never many `...value` methods in stdlib, but see `ObjectIdentifier` and `StaticString`). Note also in the Swift 3 style guidelines that type conversions are only discussed in terms of init's. Never methods.

Comment: Cool, more curious than anything. Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could put my hands on a specific "here is the history," but it's much more "every time I bring up `.array` on `LazySequence` to replace `Array.init`, I'm reminded by one of the team that there is a preference for `init`.

Answer (score 5):

### Swift 5.4

This is a more generic approach which is applicable for other types than just Int.

```
extension ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    init(_ booleanLiteral: BooleanLiteralType) {
        self = booleanLiteral ? 1 : 0
    }
}

let bool1 = true
let bool2 = false

let myInt = Int(bool1) // 1
let myFloat = Float(bool1) // 1
let myDouble = Double(bool2) // 0
let myCGFloat = CGFloat(bool2) // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

`unsafeBitCast` is always an option

```
let int: Int = Int(unsafeBitCast(someBool, to: UInt8.self))
```

Comment: Offering an explanation is _always_ useful on Stack Overflow, but it's _especially_ important where the question has been resolved to the satisfaction of the community. Help readers out by explaining what your answer does different and when it might be preferred. Can you [edit] your question to add more detail?

Comment: That doesn't seem safe

Answer (score 0):

You could use **hashValue** property:

```
let active = true
active.hashValue // returns 1
active = false
active.hashValue // returns 0
```

Comment: If you do this in Swift 4.2, you are going to get values like 482808648934333090 and similar.

Comment: Yes, you can look at this Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/q/52116428/4711785

Answer (score 0):

Tested in swift 3.2 and swift 4

There is not need to convert it into **Int**

Try this -

```
let p1 = ("a" == "a") //true

print(true)           //"true\n"
print(p1)             //"true\n"

Int(true)             //1

print(NSNumber(value: p1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 5:

you can do this:

```
let x = ("a" == "a")

Int(truncating: x as NSNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my preferred adaptation of existing solutions, just an overload of Int. This way I don't have to remember any additional syntax.

```
func Int(_ boolean: Bool) -> Int {
    boolean ? 1 : 0
}
```