# "'init' is deprecated" warning after Swift4 convert

Tags: swift, swift4

In Swift3, I previously converted a Bool to an Int using the following method

```
let _ = Int(NSNumber(value: false))
```

After converting to Swift4, I'm getting a "'init' is deprecated" warning. How else should this be done?

Comment: That's very unrealistic code. Why not `let _ = false ? 1 : 0`

Comment: You're right, that makes a lot more sense, I'll use that. Thanks!

Comment: @Vadian - I'm a n00b. I don't understand why bother with a trinary operator if you're going to feed it "false". Why not just `let _ = 0`?

Comment: @JamesTSnell It's just an example how to create an `Int` from a `Bool`. In practice `false` is supposed to be a variable.

Comment: Thanks vadian. That seems quite obvious now. Maybe I'd had too much wine? ^_^

Answer (score 28, accepted):

With Swift 4.2 and Swift 5, you can choose one of the 5 following solutions in order to solve your problem.

---

## #1. Using `NSNumber`'s `intValue` property

```
import Foundation

let integer = NSNumber(value: false).intValue
print(integer) // prints 0
```

---

## #2. Using type casting

```
import Foundation

let integer = NSNumber(value: false) as? Int
print(String(describing: integer)) // prints Optional(0)
```

---

## #3. Using `Int`'s [`init(exactly:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2804478-init) initializer

```
import Foundation

let integer = Int(exactly: NSNumber(value: false))
print(String(describing: integer)) // prints Optional(0)
```

As an alternative to the previous code, you can use the more concise code below.

```
import Foundation

let integer = Int(exactly: false)
print(String(describing: integer)) // prints Optional(0)
```

---

## #4. Using `Int`'s [`init(truncating:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2895046-init) initializer

```
import Foundation

let integer = Int(truncating: false)
print(integer) // prints 0
```

---

## #5. Using control flow

Note that the following sample codes do not require to import Foundation.

*Usage #1 (if statement):*

```
let integer: Int
let bool = false

if bool {
    integer = 1
} else {
    integer = 0
}
print(integer) // prints 0
```

*Usage #2 (ternary operator):*

```
let integer = false ? 1 : 0
print(integer) // prints 0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use NSNumber property intValue:

```
let x = NSNumber(value: false).intValue
```

You can also use `init?(exactly number: NSNumber)` initializer:

```
let y = Int(exactly: NSNumber(value: false))
```

or as mentioned in comments by @Hamish the numeric initializer has been renamed to `init(truncating:)`

```
let z = Int(truncating: NSNumber(value: false))
```

or let Xcode implicitly create a NSNumber from it as mentioned by @MartinR

```
let z = Int(truncating: false)
```

Another option you have is to extend protocol BinaryInteger (Swift 4) or Integer (Swift3) and create your own non fallible initializer that takes a Bool as parameter and returns the original type using the ternary operator as suggested in comments by @vadian:

```
extension BinaryInteger {
    init(_ bool: Bool) {
        self = bool ? 1 : 0
    }
}
```

---

```
let a = Int(true)   // 1
let b = Int(false)  // 0

let c = UInt8(true)  // 1
let d = UInt8(false) // 0
```

Comment: Great, it works! Is there a reason why the previous method is deprecated?

Comment: In Swift 4 even `let x = Int(exactly: false)!` works

Comment: The `init(_:)` initialisers to convert from `NSNumber` to Swift numeric types were renamed to `init(truncating:)` as per [SE-0170](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0170-nsnumber_bridge.md) – so `Int(truncating: NSNumber(value: false))`. But `.intValue` should achieve the same result in this case (although of course as vadian points out, there's no need to go via `NSNumber` for this in the first place).

Comment: @vadian: `let x = Int(exactly: false)` implicitly creates a `NSNumber` from the boolean.

Comment: ... and wouldn't compile without importing Foundation.