# How to multiply a float by a bool value of 0 or 1?

Tags: swift, function, boolean

My code below gives a breakpoint error:

```
func doScore(num: Float, binaural: Bool, noise: Bool) -> Float {


if 50 ... 100 ~= num{

  let numDoubled = num + (Float(noise.intValue()!) * weighting)// <--- this is where I get my error 
  return numDoubled.rounded()


}
```

All I want to do is multiply the number I am putting into the function by the value of binaural or noise which are boolean values. To do this I am getting the Int value however I need it to be a float as 0 or 1 since the number I am putting in is a float. Why would this cause a crash? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing a simple workaround, you can fix it easily

```
let numDoubled = num + (noise ? weighting : 0.0)
```

[Converting bool into int is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40242702/converting-boolean-value-to-integer-value-in-swift-3) but in my solution, there's no need to do double job( convert to int and then again convert into float)

Updated as per *vacawama* comment

**Updated answer from your comment:**

```
let numDoubled = num + ( (noise && binaural) ? weighting : 0.0 ) )
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it a workaround since multiplying a float by boolean does not make any sense :)

Comment: I like this it works well, is there a way of multiplying by both NOISE and BINAURAL? My example is: 

let numOutput = num * (noise && binaural  ? weighting : 0.0)

So I basically want to multiply by both binaural and noise even if either of them is 0 or false in this case. :)

In essence I am trying to get it to multiply by both binaural and noise and then the weighting.

Comment: @LukeIreton Updated my answer pls check. If you want multiply, replace the `+` with `*`.

Comment: If I answer with 100 and both binaural and noise = true then I just get 125 as my return num, that works great but I am basically trying to get it to where it will multiply the number I put in by binaural and noise and then the weighting. If I put in 100 and binaural and noise are true the output should be 150 if I put in 100 and only one of the bools is false it will only multiply it by 1 and then by the weighting giving the output of 125. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Mani, I have figured out the last part on my own. :)

Answer (score 3):

Unlike in (Objective-)C where `nil`, `0`, and `false` are treated as the same value depending on the environment `Int`  and `Bool` are not related in Swift and a Swift `Bool` doesn't have an `intValue`.

Practically you want to add `weighting` to `num` if `noise` is `true`.

```
let numDoubled = noise ? num + weighting : num
```

---

If you really need to convert `false` to `0` and `true` to `1` write

```
let boolAsInt = aBool ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though implicit conversion between `bool` and numeric types has been removed, you can explicitly convert a `bool` to numeric types by first converting it to an `NSNumber`.

```
let numDoubled = num + Float(truncating: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: noise)) * weighting
```

You can also do `Float(truncating: noise)` as a shorthand notation, but that call implicitly converts the `bool` to an `NSNumber`, so for clarity its better to write out the conversion explicitly.