# Bool.hashValue valid to convert to Int?

Tags: swift, hash, type-conversion, boolean, swift4

In some cases and some code I saw that `hashValue` is used to convert `Bool` to `Int`.

However, the code

```
let someValue = true
let someOtherValue = false

print(someValue.hashValue)
print(someOtherValue.hashValue)
```

gets me the output

```
-5519895559129191040
7814522403520016984
```

I would expect `1` and `0`, though.

I use XCode 10.0 beta 2 (10L177m), MacOS High Sierra with Swift 4.2. I can switch to Swift 4.0 to gain likewise results.

Now, is there something I do wrong or is `hashValue` no reliable conversion method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `hashValue` is not a proper way to convert some other type to an `Int`, especially if you want specific results.

From the documentation for `Hashable hashValue`:

> Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future execution.

The simplest solution to convert a `Bool` to `Int` is:

```
let someInt = someBool ? 1 : 0
```

Answer (score 2):

> is hashValue no reliable conversion method?

From the `.hashValue` [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue):

> Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future execution.

Comment: Nice answer, thank you! rmaddy is a bit more explicit and gives some alternative method (albeit not asked for), I therefore decided to mark his answer. Hope, you understand. I upvoted your answer, too, though